# Hibernate Session Closed Exception During Recursive call to a method

Tags: java, hibernate, recursion

In my application i have a situation where i need to do a recursive call to a method to achieve requirement.

But when i call the method I am getting

```
_Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:410)
at com.cerner.core.dao.oracleImpl.test.TestRecurssionSessionClose.fact(TestRecurssionSessionClose.java:40)
at com.cerner.core.dao.oracleImpl.test.TestRecurssionSessionClose.main(TestRecurssionSessionClose.java:49)
```

_

I have test code for this

```
public class TestRecurssionSessionClose {
private SessionFactory factory;
private Session session;
private Transaction transaction;

public TestRecurssionSessionClose() {
    HibernateUtil.configureSessionFactory();
    factory = HibernateUtil.getFactory();
}

public int fact(int n) {
    System.out.println(factory.isClosed());
    session = factory.openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;

        } else {
            System.out.println(n);
            return (n * fact(n - 1));
        }
    } catch (

    HibernateException ex) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();
        return 0;
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestRecurssionSessionClose testRecurssionSessionClose = new TestRecurssionSessionClose();
    System.out.println(testRecurssionSessionClose.fact(3));
}
```

}

I am new to hibernate. please tell me what I am  missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default some hibernate versiones have **`hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session`** to `true`. This makes that the session is closed automatically without requirement to close.

Disable the auto close session or better use [automatic session context management](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session)

See: [Session configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html)